# Why do I need all the mess from twitter, if only one line matters?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I was looking for a way to embed tweet on my page. No problems, their [documentation describes](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets) it nicely. So I go and copy something like this

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
    <p>Fixture Adapters - Ember.js With No Server: <a href="http://t.co/y3fCYK6YGw">http://t.co/y3fCYK6YGw</a></p>
    &mdash; JavaScript Daily (@JavaScriptDaily) <a href="https://twitter.com/JavaScriptDaily/statuses/470285121430781952">May 24, 2014</a>
</blockquote`>
```

But then I checked almost nothing matters there. Out of all this mess, this is enough:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/JavaScriptDaily/statuses/470285121430781952"></a>
</blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So I can only copy one line `https://twitter.com/JavaScriptDaily/statuses/470285121430781952` and recreate everything.

So is there a reason to have all that mess, if one line is enough?

Comment: Because the extra information gives context to the link?

Comment: @Andy but it is completely redundant and basically I highly doubt there is a point of having it there. When you embedd youtube video - would you like to have "context to the link"?

Comment: Then that is your personal opinion and as such does not make a good question for SO.

Comment: @Andy you do not understand my question. Please read it properly. I am asking is there a reason to have that mess. So it is not an opinion, I am asking is there some reason to have it.

Comment: I gave you an answer in my comment and you disagreed with it. How's that not a matter of opinion?

Comment: @Andy I treated it as a comment. It is not even close to the answer - this is more like a wild guess. Is there anything to back up your comment? Because my opinion is that you just guessed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "mess" is there so that users with JavaScript disabled can still see the content. In your second example (which works with JavaScript enabled), a user with JavaScript disabled would see nothing at all. However in your first example (which Twitter gives you), a user with JavaScript disabled would see the raw tweet content:

```
Fixture Adapters - Ember.js With No Server: http://t.co/y3fCYK6YGw
— JavaScript Daily (@JavaScriptDaily) May 24, 2014
```

The JavaScript is there to wrap the tweet with Twitter's controls (Follow, Retweet, Favourite, etc.). The reason it also re-loads the Tweet text itself is to prevent the host of the embedded tweet maliciously changing its content.

Comment: This is actually a good explanation. Thank you.